# Trying to install wordpress on my local machine running on Ubuntu 19.10, I keep getting 'Alias /blog /usr/share/wordpress Alias: command not found'

Tags: software-installation, apache2, 19.10, wordpress

Hi I am trying to install wordpress on my local machine through instructions on the ubuntu guide 'https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress' and the instruction are as below;

> 3. Configure Apache for WordPress
>
> Create Apache site for WordPress.
>
> Create /etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf with following lines:
>
> ```
> Alias /blog /usr/share/wordpress
> <Directory /usr/share/wordpress>
>    Options FollowSymLinks
>    AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
>    DirectoryIndex index.php
>    Order allow,deny
>    Allow from all
> </Directory>
> <Directory /usr/share/wordpress/wp-content>
>     Options FollowSymLinks
>     Order allow,deny
>     Allow from all
> </Directory>
> ```

And as soon as I punch in the first command line i get a result of

```
"Alias /blog /usr/share/wordpress
Alias: command not found"
```

Comment: Commands are case-sensitive: `Alias` is indeed not a command. `alias` is a command.

Answer (score 2):

You won't paste these lines to the command line.

Instead,

> Create /etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf with following lines

Run

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf
```

Paste the lines and save the files.

Comment: Thanks, i managed to follow the instruction and pasted, but now whaen i press enter just goes one line down and does not enter them, how do I go about hitting enter for them?